# How can i make 'individual' appended elements with onclick

Tags: javascript, append, checkbox

I keep getting stuck on this one little thing.
I append a checkbox and a remove button with an append button.

So every time the append button is clicked i get;

Checkbox and a remove button.
The remove button has to remove the checkbox.
My problem;

If i append a bunch of pairs, only the first pair seems to work :O !!

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you connecting to the onclick events? Are there any errors that is halting execution? What browser? Got any code?

Comment: Post your code, so we can tell you what's wrong, like Stephen said, it's probably a problem with duplicate ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are changing the name/id on the checkbox or you are using an array, for example

Checkbox 1 is named checkbox[1]
Checkbox 2 is named checkbox[2]

If they have the same name, they will only come through as 1 item in the POST/GET!